# How to create an infinite easing in and out CSS animation loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I want to animate the border of a popup when it is ready to receive draggable elements, i.e. has the class "accepting".  I've created a finite ease-in animation, which gives the border a nice blue glowy effect. It's OK as it is, but ideally I'd like the effect to ease in and out and in again on an infinite loop while the popup has the class 'accepting'. Here be my code.

```
if(popup.hasClass('accepting')) {
   popup.css({
          '-webkit-transition': 'all 0.3s ease-in-out',
          'outline': 'none',
          'padding': '3px 0px 3px 3px',
          'margin': '5px 1px 3px 0px',
          'box-shadow': '0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1)',
        })
}
```

I've seen some threads on here asking similar questions but the solutions involved using @webkit-keyframes selectors, and I don't think I can include additional selectors inside the .css({}) jQuery method. Is there a simpler way that I can implement here, in my JavaScript code?

Thx u
- Gaweyne

Comment: Nay, that didn't work, tried something similar before. But of course, I don't need to use the conditional at all in JavaScript :s I could do it in a separate stylesheet using the .accepting {} selector. I'll have a look at the longer solutions elsewhere see if they work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use CSS animations with `animation-iteration-count:infinite`.
Something like:

```
@keyframes glow{
    100% {
        outline: none;
        padding: 3px 0 3px 3px;
        margin: 5px 1px 3px 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
    }
}
.glow-border {
    animation-name: glow;
    animation-duration: 0.35s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

Changing your code:

```
if(popup.hasClass('accepting')) {
   popup.addClass('glow-border');
}
```

Check out CSS animations docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and don't forget to prefix it.

Comment: You beat me to it by seconds. Got something similar now, but thanks for reply.